# Dompdf: "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp, rendering, dompdf

Consistently (meaning every time) I try to load a relatively large amount of HTML related to a client form into dompdf. I get either the subject error message or, occasionally, some other error. If I comment out the code for any one of what would be 9 pages in a PDF document, it works.

I've had the same problem in the past with variable length reports (this is a form that is always 9 pages) once a certain indeterminate critical mass of data is reached. Other posts I've seen related to this issue always include follow up comments insisting that the original poster provide the HTML. I tried to do that but it far exceeds the limit allowed.

To reduce the amount of HTML would result in HTML that dompdf would have no problem rendering, so I'm not sure how to proceed to get a resolution for this.  I could provide a link to the page but it would require a userid & password for access and the resulting page would include information that is not for public consumption.

If there is no help to be had here can anyone suggest another forum where I could get help?

Here are a few specifics about the HTML that I can list that might be of help in diagnosing the problem:

- It's built almost entirely using HTML tables.
- None of the tables span
  multiple pages.
- There are no textarea controls.

Comment: the error's clear - your script's taking longer than 30 seconds to execute, and PHP's killing it. Either increase (or eliminate) the max execution time limit, improve your code so it's more efficient and can get the job done within the time limit, or split it up so that each individual portion falls under the limit.

Comment: The tables do not span pages, but do any of the table cells? That's really the only place where dompdf has trouble with tables. Though, generally, dompdf does use more resources when rendering tables. Also, which version of dompdf are you using?

Comment: Do you have any images in your PDF document? When I've used dompdf in the past with large images it tends to crash, but after reducing the image size it seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm relatively certain the error has nothing to do with a time limit, but more so with the volume of text.  I created another very similar form that when it reached 9 pages resulted in a "no data received" message.  I don't think there's a problem with my code because if I remove the 'pdf' suffix and let the browser render plain HTML the page is displayed in a couple of seconds or less.  This is not a data intensive form, as it only returns one row of data from our database.  It's a form that fills in minimal information and is intended to be printed and the user fills in missing info by hand.

Comment: The only images in the form are small (2k) checkbox PNGs.  Again, if I randomly comment enough code the PDF will render.  It's not like there are certain lines of code that cause this.  And with the reports where i've had this problem, where the same type of data is being repeated over multiple rows, it works until more than a few hundred rows are returned and then it dies.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of dompdf we are using.  I had nothing to do with setting it up so will have to check on it.

Comment: Looks like we are on version 0.6.0 beta 3, based on changlog.txt

Comment: @Mike I can provide a link to a private upload. Or, if you have the time, replace the text with gibberish before you post publicly. Sometimes it really helps to be able to see the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here set time limit which in seconds. 
set_time_limit(100);
```

Comment: Adjusting the time limits for a script that renders normally (without feeding it into DomPDF) is not a solution!  Even worse, DomPDF will just crash longer, consume more memory and maintain the high CPU load longer.  @Phil Young's and Saad answers point in the same direction as well.

Comment: Yes @4levels, this is not long term solution.

Comment: This is an extremely bad solution, don't use.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues with domPdf as well, and couldn't resolve them.  I guess you could always stick an ini_set for max_execution_time in your controller if you're stuck.

Eventually I moved to [MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) and this works really well for me.  It seems to be the most portable, and well maintained PHP HTML to PDF library that I've found.

I'm not sure I should post this as an answer or a comment, let me know if this should be a comment instead.

Comment: hello @Ben i am using mpdf but in mpdf when my content of page is more then one page at that time it's not work thats why i am trying to dompdf.
if you ave solution of my problem in mpdf then explain

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me and the problem was rather a small one.

Apart from increasing the timelimit, do check if your content is overflowing or not, I was setting paper size as A4, but when I changed it to A3, the page rendered correctly and hence didnt took long amount of time (for library to figure out the page overflow)

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper('A3','landscape'); //Changed A4 to A3
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
```

Comment: Just a note: it's `setPaper()` for newer versions ([more info](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage))

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered, but I'd just like to add, DOMPDF doesn't like nested tables

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/04/29/php-dompdf-render-timeout-problem/

Comment: Adjusting the time limits for a page that renders normally (without feeding it into DomPDF) is not a solution and even makes it worse as DomPDF will just crash longer, consume more memory and maintain the high CPU load longer.  
I can confirm that nested tables, tables spanning pages, overlowing content are all sore points in DomPDF (I even had false positives on virus detection due to HTML content corner cases).
MPDF seems no longer active, I have better results with http://wkhtmltopdf.org, it's worth the pain to setup it up.

Comment: @4levels I ended up going to [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) too, but I used the [knp-snappy library](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) as my PHP library to sit inbetween, no problems at all since I did that about a month or two after I wrote this post. Used it in all my projects since too.